# format text cell for empty values and color cell for all negative values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, heatmap

I am generating a plotly heatmap as follow:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [
        Input('submit', 'n_clicks')
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_plot(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        my_row = ['T-3', 'T-2', 'T-1']
        col = ['T-2', 'T-1', 'T0']
        df_stat = pd.DataFrame([[12, -3.5, 7.8], [np.nan, 0.5, -19], [np.nan, np.nan, 56]], columns=col)
        df_stat.index = my_row

        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
            x=df_stat.columns,
            y=df_stat.index,
            z=df_stat.values.tolist(),
            # zauto=True,
            zmax=0.67,
            zmin=0,
            hoverongaps=False,
            showscale=True,
            colorscale='OrRd',
            text=df_stat.to_numpy(), 
            texttemplate="%{text}",
            hovertemplate='My number: %{z:.2f}<extra></extra>',
            textfont={"color": "black"},
            # autocolorscale=True
        ))
        fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed", type='category', categoryorder='array', categoryarray=my_row)
        fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True, side='top', type='category', categoryorder='array', categoryarray=col)
        fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1200)

        return fig
```

The dataframe used as input is triangular (made of np.nan and floats). What I am trying to archieve is the following:

- for the lower triangular part the text should be "" and not nan or null. The background color for these "empty" cells should be transparent.
- for the colorscale, would it be possible to have it applied to only to positive values? Hence having "OrRd" colorscale for the positive values and light grey for any negative value? I tried setting zmin/zmax but then the negative values get the colorscale minimal color. I would be looking for a the colorscale "OrRd" with minimal value set to light grey. Having autocolorscale set to True and zauto to True seem to disregard the chosen colorscale.
- for the positive values, is possible to use the autocolorscale (ie set to True) while keeping the colorscale to "OrRd"? I played around the zauto/zmin-zmax and autocolorscale but couldn't get the desired colorscale.

This is how it currently looks:
[image: Current View/Ouput]

I am looking at something similar to this:
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to use the default parameters in plotly to achieve what you want, but we can get your desired result with a few workarounds.

To deal with `NaNs` in `df_stat` displaying as `null`, you can use the `.fillna("")` method with an empty string. The background for these cells is already transparent but the background color of the plot is showing through. Since your desired plot appears to have a white background with grey lines, we can take a shortcut and set the [template](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#view-available-themes) to `'plotly_white'`.

I don't think colorscales with multiple conditions (e.g. one color scale for `x>=0` and a single color for `x<0`) exists, so we'll need to mask your `df_stat` DataFrame and plot these as separate traces.

To achieve this, we'll make two separate masks of df_stat:

- `df_stat_non_negative` will contain the positive values of df_stat with all other values set to NaN. also I am not sure the `'OrRd'` colorscale is actually what you want since it looks like you want small positive values to be grey. What you can do specify multiple colors at the normalized values between 0 and 1. For example: if you set `colorscale=[[0, 'lightgrey'],[0.10, 'LightSalmon'],[1.0,'DarkRed']]`, you'll get lightgrey blending into lightsalmon for relatively small values in your heatmap, but the majority of the heatmap will resemble `'OrRd'`
- `df_stat_negative` will contain the negative values of df_stat with all other values set to NaN and for the heatmap, we'll create a custom `colorscale` where normalized values from 0 to 1 are both set to `grey` (this will ensure the heatmap corresponding to df_stat_negative has every cell colored grey regardless of the value). We'll also hide the colorscale for the heatmap of negative values.

Putting this all together:

```
from turtle import bgcolor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_row = ['T-3', 'T-2', 'T-1']
col = ['T-2', 'T-1', 'T0']
df_stat = pd.DataFrame([[12, -3.5, 7.8], [np.nan, 0.5, -19], [np.nan, np.nan, 56]], columns=col)
df_stat.index = my_row

## only plot positive df_stat values 
df_stat_non_negative = df_stat.copy()
df_stat_non_negative[df_stat_non_negative < 0] = np.nan
df_stat_non_negative.fillna("", inplace=True)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    x=df_stat_non_negative.columns,
    y=df_stat_non_negative.index,
    z=df_stat_non_negative.values.tolist(),
    # zauto=True,
    zmin=0,
    hoverongaps=False,
    showscale=True,
    colorscale=[[0, 'lightgrey'],[0.10, 'LightSalmon'],[1.0,'DarkRed']],
    text=df_stat_non_negative.to_numpy(), 
    texttemplate="%{text}",
    hovertemplate='My number: %{z:.2f}<extra></extra>',
    textfont={"color": "black"},
    # autocolorscale=True
))

df_stat_negative = df_stat.copy()
df_stat_negative[df_stat_negative >= 0] = np.nan
df_stat_negative.fillna("", inplace=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    x=df_stat_negative.columns,
    y=df_stat_negative.index,
    z=df_stat_negative.values.tolist(),
    # zauto=True,
    zmax=0,
    zmin=0,
    hoverongaps=False,
    showscale=False,
    colorscale=[[0, 'lightgrey'],[1.0, 'lightgrey']],
    text=df_stat_negative.to_numpy(), 
    texttemplate="%{text}",
    hovertemplate='My number: %{z:.2f}<extra></extra>',
    textfont={"color": "black"},
    # autocolorscale=True
))

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed", type='category', categoryorder='array', categoryarray=my_row)
fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True, side='top', type='category', categoryorder='array', categoryarray=col)
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1200, template='plotly_white')
fig.show()
```

[image]